# Selenium: Python ActionChains doesn't work

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to do a simple Control + S in Chromedriver

I tried `webdriver.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL, "s")` which didn't work

I then tried

```
ActionChains(driver).key_down(Keys.LEFT_CONTROL).key_down('s').perform()
```

which still doesn't work.

What other alternative do I have? When I manually press CONTROL + S in the chromedriver browser, it works. Why can't selenium do this?

I am using Selenium Python.

Comment: "Didn't work" means..?

Answer (score 3):

Send keys to the `Body` element:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

body = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body')
body.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL, "s")  # on Mac: body.send_keys(Keys.COMMAND, "s")
```

---

Or, get the actual html source code this way:

```
html = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*").get_attribute("outerHTML")
print html
```

Comment: I tried sending to the body but it did not fire the save dialog. im on windows

Comment: yeah using chromedriver on windows 7. i might try it on ubuntu just to see if it works

Comment: @user299709 ok, but why do you need to fire up the "Save" dialog? Please describe the use case.

Comment: so I can save page complete.

Comment: At least, on Mac any kind of combo keys won't work...I tried many of them over Chrome but still any chance of proper working...

Answer (score -4):

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("Https://www.google.com")
body = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body')
body.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL, "s")
```

The above code is working for me on windows+firefox. please make sure that you are using latest version of Selenium [version 2.45.0](http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/)

Comment: This is the same answer as alecxe's ("send the event to `body`"), but posted many many months later.